# Aligning a logo on the right of a menu strip in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, graphical-logo, menustrip

I've got a menu strip, inside which I want to embed my company logo and align it to the right.

My project is on a Windows Form Application, sorry for not including this before.

---

Several google-trips have found little, this is probably my not using the proper terminology.

What is the best way to do this? I'd also like it to be flexible, so preferably no fixed-position methods.

Thank you.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net?

Comment: @SLaks Edited to inform you of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dock a TableLayoutPanel to the Top of the Form.  Make it have one row and two columns.  Put your MenuStrip in the left column, and a PictureBox in the right column for the Logo.  Set the right column to AutoSize, the Row to AutoSize, and the TableLayoutPanel to AutoSize.  Also set the SizeMode of the PictureBox to Autosize.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Sorry it took so long to answer, I had a lot of hold-ups the day beforehand that prevented me from implementing your solution.